# How to create program for asterisks forming a box?

Tags: javascript, html

```
*******
*     *
*  *  *
*     *
*******
```

It should look like the above arrangement of asterisks. I'm new to programming. So far I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<body>

<script>

var maxCount = 7;
var iterationCount = 0;

while (iterationCount < maxCount) {
  iterationCount = iterationCount + 1;
  document.write('*');
}
```

I have a strong feeling so far that's incorrect, and even if it's correct, I don't know how to go on from there. 
I know I have to use for and nested loops, but I'm extremely confused.

Comment: "It should look like this." Um, like what, exactly? Do you mean a square of asterisks? A hollow square, or a filled one? Please be specific.

"I have a strong feeling so far that's incorrect." Try it?

Comment: what does your output look like ?  please show

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var width = 7,
    height = 7, // for example
    boxElem = document.getElementById("box"); // this is the element which will hold your box

for(var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if(i === 0 || i === height - 1 || j === 0 || j === width - 1 || (i === Math.floor(height / 2) && j === Math.floor(width / 2))) {
            // check if it's the first or last row or column, or if it's the centre of the box
            boxElem.innerHTML += "*";
        } else {
            boxElem.innerHTML += " "; // otherwise, don't add an asterisk but an empty space
        }
    }
    boxElem.innerHTML += "\n"; // new line
}
```